# Typo3 9.5 Language dependent variables rendered in Fluid

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I'm using Typo3 9.5 and got some hardcoded variables within my fluid templates. I'm trying to make this variables depending on what language the page is viewed. Default value works fine. But making use of TypoScript like

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
   #whatever
[end]
```

for instance already throws an Error within the console either way and therefore does not override an variable. I think I've done this before in previous Typo3 versions. How do I achieve language depending variables and render it within my FLUID template?

Comment: What do you mean with variables? Can you show us the related Fluid part?

Maybe it would help to provide a bit more context. Like current TypoScript involved and Fluid involved.

If it's hard coded and language specific, I would suggest a translation file and `f:translate` ViewHelper.

Comment: I'm talking about simple TEXT variables, for instance the placeholder of an input field, I want the value to be 'search' for English and 'recherche' for French etc.

Comment: Then see Claus Due answer, the translation is the way to go, do not use Variables but translations.

This doesn't sound like Variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be assigning your variables this way. The right way to handle this is to create XLF files that can be referenced with `f:translate` to translate a given key into any language as long as there's an XLF file for it.

This method is used and supported throughout TYPO3, not just in Fluid. Nearly all labelling options support `LLL:...` references where you can point to specific files.

You are encouraged to create an extension that can contain such files and then reference them with `LLL:EXT...` paths and/or use `extensionName` on `f:translate` in your Fluid templates if the extension is other than the one rendering your Fluid templates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Claus. I was talking about a single HTML-field within my Fluid template. I only got 2 or two hardcoded variables within my Fluid. Wouldn't an extension be an overkill for that?

Comment: There is no need for an Extension, you can also use files from fileadmin.

But today an extension called "Sitepackage" is considered best practice to contain language files and templates. There is no "overkill" as an extension is just a single folder and an ext_emconf.php + what you consider to be necessary.

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/

Comment: Allright, I now got the point. Sorry for the confusion. I'm using the sitepackage by Ben Kott anyway and see it already contains .xlf Files. I now have to find out how to create terms and their translations within these files and how to include them in my template :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the use of XLF files. This worked perfectly!